# Creating a method which returns one or two parameters generically

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a method

```
def foo(num: Int): String
```

Where I call some in some places in my code, and everything was good.
Lately, I encountered a situation where I need to call the **same method**, but with some parameter int value, I need to get in return **2 Strings**, and not only one.  My current way of implementing it is:

```
def foo(num: Int): List[String]
```

Where each time I call `foo` and get **1** String, I will get the head of the list, and each time I call for and it returns 2 strings, I will get the elements in [0, 1] (I know that when I call `foo(10)`, I get 2 strings, and for the rest - only one).

Is there a more idiomatic scala/functional for this?

Comment: Do you statically know where do you need two values? Or is a runtime behavior?

Comment: Statically. Everytime I call `foo(10)`, I know I will get 2 strings, and not one.

Comment: But my question is, do you know in which places of the code are you going to have a `10`?

Comment: How is that "static"? You mean when the parameter is 10, you have two results, otherwise just one?

Comment: Yes, when the parameter is 10, I have two results, otherwise just one - and I know where in code I call `foo(10)` and where I don't.

Comment: Just have two functions. They are different. Also, if you know that the two values behavior happens when you have a `10` and just a `10` and probably the two values are always the same, that is not a function, just a constant.

Answer (score 15):

**Scala 2.13** introduced literal-based singleton types, so actually you can do a crazy thing like this:

```
def foo(num: 10): (String, String) = ("Hello", "World")
def foo(num: Int): String = s"Hello $num"

val (left, right) = foo(10)
val single = foo(2)
```

and it will [compile and work](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/4s68LKHdTcGRe8pxTtJjvQ).

Of course, you can return a list instead of a tuple for the *10* case if you wish.

It should also work for **typelevel scala** (even before **2.13**).

With regular **Lightbend Scala** before **2.13** you could still do that, but it was a lot clunkier. It was necessary to use an additional trick involving using type called *Witness*, but fortunately, it is provided by *shapeless*:

```
import shapeless.Witness
import shapeless.syntax.singleton._

def foo(num: Witness.`10`.T): (String, String) = ("Hello", "World")
def foo(num: Int): String = s"Hello $num"

val (left, right) = foo(10)
val single = foo(2)
```

And of course it is necessary to add *shapeless* as dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.3.3"
```

---

Another approach you could use is just the use of some kind of special container for your result. I would recommend tuple: `(String, Option[String])`. In case you're returning "regular" result, you would return `(String, None)` and in case of *10* you can return `(String, Some[String])`.

Answer (score 4):

Since the result space is cleanly split into two sides (disjointed) consider `Either` like so

```
def foo(i: Int): Either[(String, String), String] =
  if (i == 10) Left("one", "two") else Right("one")

val Left(Tuple2(x, y)) = foo(10)
val Right(a) = foo(2)
```

which is inspired by @Krzysztof's edit regarding "special container".