# Assigning to array of type argument

Tags: scala

I have simple function

```
def test[T](param: Boolean): Array[T] = {
  val s = 0.to(20).map {v =>
    if (param) v.toString else v -> v
  }
  s.toArray[T]
}

test[String](true)
```

depends on value of function agrument **param** i get a sequence of String or (Int, Int) values to **s** variable... But now how can i return the array? The way i do i get an exception

> type arguments [T] do not conform to method toArray's type parameter
>   bounds [B >: Any]

Thanks in advance

Comment: What if I call `test[ZonedDateTime](param = true)` how would the **String** be magically converted to a **ZonedDateTime**?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, so i can not use [T] arguments in may case?

Comment: What exactly did you want to achive? You want to return **Strings** if the param is `true` and **Ints** if `false`, right? Also, any reason to be using **Arrays**? those are usually reserved for performance-sensitive algorithms, as they are unsafe, usually you should use immutable data structures like **List** or **Vector**.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return either one type or *either* the other, you should use [**Either**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Either.html).

```
def test(param: Boolean): Either[Array[String], Array[(Int, Int]]] =
  if (param) Left((0 to 20).map(_.toString).toArray)
  else Right((0 to 20).map(v => v -> v).toArray)
```

Comment: I know what is Either... My question is not what i SHOULD use but to understand how it works. If i want to return either one type or either another ot either third one? (about arrays 0.to(N).toArray works 2 times faster than toList)

Comment: @DmitryReutov What exactly do you want to understand? The compiler has to verify that your problem is correct. A compile.time property like the return type of a method can not depend on a runtime value. There are many solutions to this situation, but all those depend on what exactly do you want, on how do you want to use your function. - Finally, about the performance, of `toList` vs `toArray` in most cases that shouldn't worry you, but I won't go to the rabbit hole of that discussion, for that reason I limited myself to use **Array** as you want.

Comment: Luis, i want just the direct answer to my direct question... Either example how can i convert from Array[String] to Array[T] or stating the fact that such conversion is not possible...Thats it...Yes there are many solutions to this situation and inspite i'm new to scala i can find 2 or 3 myself, but i just wanted to understand [T] issue works

Comment: @DmitryReutov No, you can not _(safely)_ cast a `Array[String]` to an `Array[T]` because **T** may be anything, and it is in control of the user. Just as plain as that. Scala is a **statically** & **strong** typed language, this is not **Python** or **Javascript** where the types are dynamic and weaker. So, no, your code as it is written doesn't make sense. However, what I am trying to do is explain to you, that based on your exact requirements there are ways to refactor the function to make it compile and express your intent.

Answer (score 1):

Try *literal singleton types* as suggested by [Krzysztof](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57946755/5205022) like so

```
def test(param: true): Array[String] = {
  0.to(20).map(v => v.toString).toArray
}
def test(param: false): Array[(Int, Int)] = {
  0.to(20).map(v => v -> v).toArray
}

test(true)
test(false)
```

which outputs

```
res0: Array[String] = ArraySeq(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
res1: Array[(Int, Int)] = ArraySeq((0,0), (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5), (6,6), (7,7), (8,8), (9,9), (10,10), (11,11), (12,12), (13,13), (14,14), (15,15), (16,16), (17,17), (18,18), (19,19), (20,20))
```

Comment: Thanks, thats a funny option, but still two thing remain: 1) There's a lot of code inside loop which i dont want to duplicate but if move it to a separate function then again the same issue with types or i should somehow break the code to type dependent/independent parts which is not very nice... But this stuff i can solve 2) Another thing - i pass to function not just false or true, but an object with 5 extending cases, 2 of them should invoke first type, another 3 - second type. Yes, i can create 5 different funcs but it becomes bit complicated. Anyway the example is precious, thanx!

Comment: @DmitryReutov It would be good if you can open a new question explaining your problem in detail so we can provide various solutions, each with their tradeoffs.

Answer (score 1):

Note: The following code only works in dotty(i.e. Scala 3.0):

```
scala> type R[b] = b match { case true => Array[String]; case false => Array[(Int, Int)] }

scala> def test[B <: true|false](param: B): R[B] =
     |   (if(param) (0 to 20).map(_.toString).toArray 
     |    else (0 to 20).map(x => (x, x)).toArray).asInstanceOf 
def test[B <: true | false](param: B): R[B]

scala> test(true) 
val res0: Array[String] = 
Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)

scala> test(false) 
val res1: Array[(Int, Int)] = 
Array((0,0), (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5), (6,6), (7,7), (8,8), (9,9), 
      (10,10), (11,11), (12,12), (13,13), (14,14), (15,15), (16,16), (17,17), 
      (18,18), (19,19), (20,20))
```

Comment: I believe in Scala 3 it would be better to use an inline method for this.