# Return a child class from apply method of base trait

Tags: scala

I'm struggling to understand if it possible for a `apply` function to return an instance of a specific class. Here is an example:

I have an abstract trait

```
trait BaseTrait {
  def add(s: Int): Int
}
```

and two classes that inherit this trait and:

1. override an abstract method
2. specify a method `another_method`

```
class Child1 extends BaseTrait {

  override def add(s: Int): Int = {
    s + s
  }

  def another_method(): Unit = {
    println("Another method in Child1")
  }
}

class Child2 extends BaseTrait {

  override def add(s: Int): Int = {
    s + s
  }

  def another_method(): Unit = {
    println("Another method in Child2")
  }
}
```

When I try to access the contents of child classes from a utility function in a Base Trait

```
object BaseTrait {
  def apply(t: String): BaseTrait = {
    t match {
      case "one" => new Child1()
      case "two" => new Child2()
    }
  }
}

val child2 = BaseTrait("one")
```

i don't see `another_method` method

```
child2.another_method() // cannot resolve symbol another method
```

**Question:** is there a way in Scala (generics/lower-upper bounds) to configure an `apply` method in such a way that it returns an instances of classes where it will be possible to access both overridden abstract methods AND methods belonging to this exact class (not just those that are defined in BaseTrait)

Comment: You need to understand the difference between compile-time types and runtime classes. Yes, the returned value of `BaseTrait("one")` is an instance of the **Child1** class, but it is statically typed as a **BaseTrait**; so for the compiler, it doesn't have the `another_method` method, since **BaseTrait** doesn't define it. - There is no way to change that, given the returned class depends on runtime information, for example assume this `BaseTrait(str)` where str is read from a file, how do you know which class it is going to be? you can't. - This is the core idea of abstraction and polymorphism

Comment: Thank you! And there is no way to use advanced typing techniques to make this possible, correct?

Comment: It depends. Is the family of types closed? Then you can use **pattern matching**. Or if the information doesn't come from runtime but rather compile time constants, there are tricks like Mario show. You can also rethink you solution so you can get the correct type. Or you can just throw a dirty `asInstanceOf` if you are totally sure what the class is going to be _(spoiler alert, this is usually a really bad idea)_. - So, in other words, if you want a particular solution for a particular problem then describe it with all the details, but a general answer is no, this is usually not possible.

Comment: The approach I'm describing is taken from [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/write-clean-and-solid-scala-spark-jobs-28ac4395424a). Particularly, you can look at the code in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ronald-smith-angel/eb9bab8a1e029eadf96ec92cff6dffd4#file-cleanerservice-scala).

Comment: The main idea is to have a BaseTrait implementing a base logic for all cleaning (or enrichment) transformations for a single source in a single Spark pipeline. But the problem comes when you have multiple sources (therefore multiple classes that inherit a BaseTrait) that require additional logic. I don't want this additional logic (addition method) to reside in a base trait. I want them to be in their respective classes (Child1, Child2 in our example).

Comment: Yeah, that is ok, but why do you want to instantiate them using a **String**?

Comment: @Eugene why not to abstract over any cleaning with a single `clean` method? why do you need different types in the base trait and some additional in others?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez it is an implementation i try to follow without any concern about whether it is reasonable or not :) Is there a better way to instantiate them?

Comment: @ArtemSokolov I think the main idea is to have a container with base cleaning logic for all sources that is "closed for modification and open for extension". But if I want a custom cleaning logic per Spark source (i.e. per class extending base trait) I have no way to do it. I can only define ALL methods in a single base trait and then all classes will have to implement ALL of these methods which seems unreasonable.

Comment: Why not just call the constructor of the class you want?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez yes, it seems like the most reasonable thing to do

Comment: @Eugene nope, I thoght about something different.
If your service is about clean - just make base 1 pulic method `clean(...)` and realize it in each subtype correspondingly. This is a design that corresponds to SOLID.

If you want to reuse common logic you can use a static object, or helpers, or other services that will be injected in services that need to share common logic.

If you need to struggle through types - it probably is a bad design and abstractions.

Answer (score 8):

In this particular case you could try [literal types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57946591/creating-a-method-which-returns-one-or-two-parameters-generically/57946755#57946755)

```
object BaseTrait {
  def apply(t: "one"): Child1 = new Child1()
  def apply(t: "two"): Child2 = new Child2()
}

val child1 = BaseTrait("one")
child1.another_method()
// Another method in Child1
```

Answer (score 4):

Besides overloading you can also try a type class

```
object BaseTrait {
  def apply[S <: String with Singleton](t: S)(implicit tc: MyTypeclass[S]): tc.Out = tc()
}

trait MyTypeclass[S <: String] {
  type Out <: BaseTrait
  def apply(): Out
}
object MyTypeclass {
  implicit val one = new MyTypeclass["one"] {
    override type Out = Child1
    override def apply() = new Child1()
  }

  implicit val two = new MyTypeclass["two"] {
    override type Out = Child2
    override def apply() = new Child2()
  }
}

val child2 = BaseTrait("one")

child2.another_method()
```

(Scala 2.13)